# How to insert data from other tables when the destination table has primary keys?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I need help creating a table the can track a 2% yearly price increase over the years 2010-2016. My create statement is as follows:

[image]

I have 24 products and the starting price in my Products table that need insert into my new table. In theory I should have 192 records. I need help populating the year column so that it can cycle though 2010-2016 for each product. I also need help referencing the previous year price for the next years calculation.

[[image: enter image description here]]

[[image: enter image description here}]

Comment: Add some sample table (not too many rows), and it's expected result!

Comment: What DBMS are you using? The syntax may be different.

Comment: @sagi Im using SQL

Comment: Are you using for example MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, MS Access, Oracle (blergh) Interbase, Firebase? What is that screenshot from. Where does your data come from? Are you manually entering it?

Comment: SQL is a language specified by ANSI/ISO. Many products have SQL support, but only more or less standard compliant - that's why its a good idea to specify dbms!

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I am using sql server management studio. the populated table above is already in my database

Comment: I will change your tag to MS SQL for you. Do you know what version? run `SELECT @@VERSION` to find out

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1 (X64)

Answer (score 0):

```
   with product as 
       ( select 1 as productid , 
                100.0 as price),
        years(year) AS
        (
            SELECT 2011 UNION ALL SELECT 2012 UNION ALL  
            SELECT 2013 UNION ALL SELECT 2014 UNION ALL 
            SELECT 2015 UNION ALL SELECT 2016
        )           
        select 
          p.productid, 
           y.year,
           power(1.02 ,  row_number () over (partition by p.productid order by y.year)) * p.price  currYearPrice,
           power(1.02 ,  row_number () over (partition by p.productid order by y.year)-1) * p.price lastYearPrice     
         from product  p
         cross join years  y
```

The result is:

```
pID Year    CurrYPr LasYPr
1   2011    102.000 100.000
1   2012    104.000 102.000
1   2013    106.000 104.000
1   2014    108.000 106.000
1   2015    110.000 108.000
1   2016    113.000 110.000
```